# Trying to read variables of my http call at a IHttpHandler class

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have a factory that contains the function given below:

```
TestOperation: function(filename) {
    var senddata = {
        filename: filename,
        operation: 'download',
        base: '3',
    };
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://' + location.host + '/FtpHandler.ashx',
        data: senddata
    });
}
```

I am using this in order to have my `FtpHandler` class download and save a file from my ftp server.

The class looks like this

```
FtpHandler.ashx
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="FtpHandler.ashx.cs" Class="TestWebApplication.FtpHandler" %>

FtpHandler.ashx.cs
namespace TestWebApplication
{
    public class FtpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var operationType = context.Request.Form["operation"];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(operationType);
...
```

This ends up printing an empty line in my Output console.
Why is it that I cant correctly get the value for this (or any other) variable?

Comment: have you verified that the request contains your data from your request?

Comment: I can see in my `Request Payload` in Chrome `{filename: "test3.txt", operation: "download", base: "3"}. So there must be some other thing that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check `context.Request.RequestData.Values` and let us know what's in it.

Comment: After using a breakpoint to analyze `context` I dont see a `RequestData` definition anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values`

Comment: In that position the Count is 0, and there are no keys.

Comment: Okay, let's try one more thing. `context.Request.Params["operation"];`

Comment: Whats this magic??? It worked. Could you please add it as an answer and if possible explain why the keys are in this position?

Comment: Also do notice that this only works with Konstantin Zadiranis suggested edit. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple tries, it seems like you need to utilize the `Params` in order to get your data from your request.

The full code would be : `context.Request.Params["operation"];`

Your `Request.Form` parsing would be null because you aren't posting a form, nor are you even dealing with a Form on the client. You're dealing with a JavaScript object.

I know that `Request.Params` allows you to access the requests' key/value pairs whether it's a query string or a Form collection.

As for why using the `$http` module via Angular didn't work, I think your `HttpHandler` requires a specific request setup that perhaps wasn't met..but, again I'm not sure. If you're interested, you could try to set up your request differently:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': //some content-type
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your values in `QueryString`, not in `Form`

```
        var operationType = context.Request.QueryString["operation"];
```

Comment: I am afraid this returns an empty string too.

Comment: update your request to `
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://' + location.host + '/FtpHandler.ashx',
        data: senddata
    });`

Comment: This still keeps my keys Count at 0, and no data is ever displayed.

Comment: Your suggestion on using ajax together made the data show up to where MArk suggested, I have no idea why.